# Unable to use find_each to iterate over objects stored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I am trying to access each order and perform some update operation over here. However it is throwing me an error as `` NoMethodError: undefined method `find_each' for #<Array:0x00000001156a8ae0> `` when trying to run the sidekiq for background updation of one field.

Earlier when my code base was like

```
def future_orders
    order= customer_branch.ogs.recurrence_children.of_future
end

def update_orders_instruction
    OrderGroup.transaction do
        future_orders.find_each do |og|
          next if og.is_manually_updated
          instruction = [og.customer_branch&.customer.instruction,customer_branch.instruction].compact.join("\n")
          og.delivery_order.update!(instruction: instruction)
        end
    end
  end
end
```

it was working and `find_each` method was working

Now i am trying to filter `future_order` more and now my code base looks like

```
  def future_orders
    future_order= customer_branch.ogs.recurrence_children.of_future | customer_branch.ogs.of_future
    future_order.select { |order| ["Done", "InProgress"].include?(order.status) }
  end

  def update_orders_instruction
    OrderGroup.transaction do
        future_orders.find_each do |og|
          next if og.is_manually_updated
          instruction = [og.customer_branch&.customer.instruction,customer_branch.instruction].compact.join("\n")
          og.delivery_order.update!(instruction: instruction)
  
        end
    end
  end
end
```

It is not updating and the sidekiq is throwing the above error.

Comment: find_each is an ActiveRecord method -- the future_orders method has materialized the results of a query into an array already. You can use array methods to further filter or rework your future_orders method to filter using ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 2):

[`find_each`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) is method on an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. But when you call `select` on a collection, then the whole collection is loaded and filtered in memory, and an `Array` is returned. An array doesn't support `find_each`, instead you can just use `each` to iterate all elements.

Note that `find_each` has the benefit that it doesn't load all records into memory at once, but only loads smaller batches (1000 is the default). When your collection is huge, then it certainly makes sense to filter the records in the database.

Changing

```
future_order = customer_branch.ogs.recurrence_children.of_future | customer_branch.ogs.of_future
future_order.select { |order| ["Done", "InProgress"].include?(order.status) }
```

to

```
future_order = 
  customer_branch
    .ogs
    .recurrence_children
    .of_future.where(orders: { status: ['Done', 'InProgress'] }) | 
  customer_branch
    .ogs
    .of_future.where(orders: { status: ['Done', 'InProgress'] })
```

and keeping `find_each` might work for you depending on your database schema. `where(orders: { status: ['Done', 'InProgress'] })` could be a scope in the model.